# FORCE INDEX in django

Tags: mysql, sql, django

Is there a way to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `title_mediaasset` FORCE INDEX(upload_id_2)
WHERE upload_id is not null ORDER BY `upload_date` DESC
```

It would be something like:

```
MediaAsset.objects.exclude(upload__isnull=True).force_index('upload_id_2).order_by('-upload_date')
```

Is there a way to do this, outside of using `.raw()` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do this using the ORM without using raw querysets.

There was a ticket [#11003](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11003) to add this functionality, but it was closed as won't fix.